# Concat_ws() function in Sparklyr is missing

Tags: r, sparklyr

I am following a tutorial on web (Adobe) analytics, where I want to build a Markov Chain Model. (http://datafeedtoolbox.com/attribution-theory-the-two-best-models-for-algorithmic-marketing-attribution-implemented-in-apache-spark-and-r/).

In the example they are using the function: 
**concat_ws** (from library(sparklyr)). But it looks like the function does not exists (after installing the package, and calling the library, I receive an error that the function does not exists...).

**Comment author of the blog:** concat_ws is a Spark SQL function:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html
So, you’ll have to rely on sparklyr to have that function work.

My question: are there workarounds to get access to the concat_ws() function? I tried:

- Searched on Github (https://github.com/rstudio/sparklyr) if I could find the function (or the source code).. unfortunately no result..

**What is the goal of the function?**
*Concatenates multiple input string columns together into a single string column, using the given separator.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `paste` from base R.

```
library(sparklyr)
library(dplyr)

config <- spark_config()
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local", config = config)

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(c("1", "2", "3"), c("a", "b", "c")))
sdf <- sdf_copy_to(sc, df, overwrite = T)

sdf %>%
  mutate(concat = paste(V1, V2, sep = "-"))
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot find the function because it doesn't exist in `sparklyr` package. `concat_ws` is a Spark SQL function (`org.apache.spark.sql.functions.concat_ws`).

`sparklyr` depends on a SQL translation layer - function calls are translated into SQL expressions with `dbplyr`:

```
> dbplyr::translate_sql(concat_ws("-", foo, bar))
<SQL> CONCAT_WS('-', "foo", "bar")
```

This means that the function can be applied only in the `sparklyr` context:

```
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local[*]")
df <- copy_to(sc, tibble(x="foo", y="bar"))

df %>% mutate(xy = concat_ws("-", x, y))
# # Source: spark<?> [?? x 3]
#   x     y     xy     
# * <chr> <chr> <chr>  
# 1 foo   bar   foo-bar
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with dbplyr (BigQuery database).

#### Problem

I kept getting the error:

```
my_dbplyr_object %>%
  mutate(datetime_char = paste(date_char, time_char)) 
# failed x Function not found: CONCAT_WS at [1:147] [invalidQuery]
```

#### Solution

I wrote custom SQL and placed it inside `sql()`.

#### Example

Once you know the SQL that will generate what you're after (in my case it was `CONCAT(date_char, ' ', time_char)`), then simply place it inside the `sql()` function, like so:

```r
my_dbplyr_object %>%
  mutate(datetime_char = sql("CONCAT(date_char, ' ', time_char)"))
```