# Translate Spark SQL function to "normal" R code

Tags: r, dplyr, sparklyr

I am trying to follow an Vignette "How to make a Markov Chain" (http://datafeedtoolbox.com/attribution-theory-the-two-best-models-for-algorithmic-marketing-attribution-implemented-in-apache-spark-and-r/).

This tutorial is interesting, because it is using the same data source as I use. But, **a part of the code is using "Spark SQL code"** (what I got back from my previous question [Concat_ws() function in Sparklyr is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52781720/concat-ws-function-in-sparklyr-is-missing/52788604#52788604)).

My question: I googled a lot and tried to solve this by myself. But I have no idea how, since I don't know exactly what the data should look like (the author didn't gave an example of his DF before and after the function).

**How can I transform this piece of code into "normal" R code (without using Spark) (especially: the concat_ws & collect_list functions are causing trouble**

He is using this line of code:

```
channel_stacks = data_feed_tbl %>%
 group_by(visitor_id, order_seq) %>%
 summarize(
   path = concat_ws(" > ", collect_list(mid_campaign)),
   conversion = sum(conversion)
 ) %>% ungroup() %>%
 group_by(path) %>%
 summarize(
   conversion = sum(conversion)
 ) %>%
 filter(path != "") %>%
 collect()
```

From my previous question, I know that we can replace a part of the code:

> concat_ws() can be replaced the paste() function

But again, another part of code is jumping in:

```
collect_list()  # describtion: Aggregate function: returns a list of objects with duplicates.
```

I hope that I described this question as clear as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`paste` has the ability to collapse the string vector with a separator that is provided with the `collapse` parameter.

This can act as a drop in replacement for `concat_ws(" > ", collect_list(mid_campaign))`

```
channel_stacks = data_feed_tbl %>%
     group_by(visitor_id, order_seq) %>%
     summarize(
       path = paste(mid_campaign, collapse = " > "),
       conversion = sum(conversion)
     ) %>% ungroup() %>%
     group_by(path) %>%
     summarize(
       conversion = sum(conversion)
     ) %>%
     filter(path != "")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was what I was looking for.